# Linux sound programming. How to determine a buffer size in frames?

Tags: c, linux, alsa

I'm experimenting with ALSA and came across with the following configuration parameter in this [howto, Section 2](http://alsamodular.sourceforge.net/alsa_programming_howto.html):

> The unit of the buffersize depends on the function. Sometimes it is
>   given in bytes, sometimes the number of frames has to be specified.
>   One frame is the sample data vector for all channels. For 16 Bit
>   stereo data, one frame has a length of four bytes.

```
/* Set buffer size (in frames). The resulting latency is given by */
/* latency = periodsize * periods / (rate * bytes_per_frame)     */
if (snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size(pcm_handle, hwparams, (periodsize * periods)>>2) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error setting buffersize.\n");
  return(-1);
}
```

> I don't understand this For 16 Bit stereo data, one frame has a length
>   of four bytes

Why is it four? Does it follow by the number of channels: 2? I mean earlier they configured it as follows:

```
/* Set number of channels */
if (snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcm_handle, hwparams, 2) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error setting channels.\n");
  return(-1);
}
```

How about if my acoustic system contains 4 outputs? Or 6? Does it mean that I have to configre it to 16 Bit * 4 and 16 Bit * 6 correspondingly?

Comment: Well, each sample is 16bit (two bytes) and you have two channels (so multiply by two), and this makes.....  four full bytes of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it four? Does it follow by the number of channels: 2?

Yes, according to mentioned earlier:

> One frame is the sample data vector for all channels.

So for stereo 16 bit data, there are two (left and right) channels of 16 bits (=2 bytes) each, so that totals to 4 bytes per frame.

Comment: Thanks. So in case I capture data from a microphone there will be only 1 channel, so the frame size is 2 bytes. Am I correct?